# separador de miles en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

muy buenas tardes para todos.

Alguien tiene idea de como agregar un separador de miles en una variable con JavaScript?

Este es mi código:

```
function guardartre(){

var _kilo= document.getElementById("kilo").value;
var _volum= document.getElementById("volum").value;
var _cantid= document.getElementById("cantid").value;

var _impri= _kilo * _volum;
var _totales= _impri * _cantid;
        
var fila=""+
            "<input type='text' name='_totales[]' value='"+_totales+"' readonly>"+
            ""+
            
            
"<td><button onclick='eliminarFilatwo(this)' class='md-close'>-</button></td>" ;

var btn = document.createElement("TR");
btn.innerHTML=fila;
document.getElementById("pasignadotwo").appendChild(btn);
    }
```

Lo que intento hacer e que la variable:

var _totales= _impri * _cantid;

Me imprima el valor separado por miles en el caso de que aplique, ejemplo:

1.000.000,00

Actualmente solo imprime la variable normal:

1000000

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan aportar me puede ser de gran utilidad, muchas gracias.

Comment: [Hmmm...](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=separador+miles+%5Bjavascript%5D+is%3Aquestion) Y [buscando en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/search?q=separador+miles) salta [esto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

Comment: Muchas gracias, utilice esto: .toLocaleString() luego de imprimir la variable y funciono perfecto, era lo que necesitaba.

Comment: **_Busca, investiga_**. Recuerda que preguntar en [es.so] debe ser _tu último recurso_.